# Contar municipios de una sola entidad en Microsoft Access

Tags: ms-access-2010

Tengo un examen de Access 2010 para oposición este fin de semana y éste es el único ejercicio que no he conseguido hacer por mi cuenta de los que nos entregó la academia, así que agradecería que me ayudaran para ir un poco más tranquilo al examen.

Tengo una primera tabla con dos claves primarias, una de municipios y otra de entidades.

Hay municipios con una sola entidad y municipios con varias, como puede verse en el screenshot de la tabla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo una segunda tabla relacionada por la clave de municipio que tiene el siguiente aspecto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La pregunta del ejercicio es cuántos municipios tienen una sola entidad.

Imagino que habrá de solucionarse a través de una consulta a la primera tabla, pero no alcanzo a ver cómo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solo se me ocurre mediante una subconsulta

Por un lado tenemos la lista de municipios con una sola entidad:

```
select Id_Municipio, count(Id_Entidad)
from Entidades
Group by Id_Municipio
Having count(Id_Entidad) = 1
```

Para contar el número de municipios, contamos el resultado de la consulta anterior

```
select count(Id_Municipio)
from (
    select Id_Municipio, count(Id_Entidad) as Entidades
    from Entidades
    Group by Id_Municipio
    Having count(Id_Entidad) = 1
) a
```